# A book series about stones that give people power

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm trying to remember a book series (I THINK it was 7 books long) that followed a teen boy in a fantasy world. All I can really remember is that his father was thought to be dead, and in the book people could use the stones to create things (like the Green Lantern). I do remember that they forced some storm cloud beings to serve them and be their shadows.

Comment: probable duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46022/female-main-character-in-an-ice-world-earning-gems-runes (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 18):

I believe you are looking for Garth Nix's [Seventh Tower series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Seventh_Tower). The Chosen use Sunstones to bind magical creatures to them as Spiritshadows. These Sunstones also function in a manner similar to a Lantern ring in that they can create constructs of light.

The storm cloud beings you mention are Adras and Odris, Storm Shepherds, that the two protagonists encounter in the third book.

Comment: I always kinda wondered about the storm shepherds I dont remember it ever actually being stated but the impression I got was that they were very very powerful shadows to bind

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_Sky

The description reminds me of the broken sky series I read a while ago, people receive different coloured stones for different powers early in their life.