# Looking for a book about magic shadows

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember reading a book that was about a boy learning to control his shadow, everyone had their own shadow and his was particularly weak. I recall early on he had to fight someone much stronger with a dragon shadow, but that's about it. Anyone know what this book is called? I've been looking for years, and all my attempts have turned up empty. I believe he may have been attending some sort of school, I think the fight with the dragon shadow was some sort of coming of age test. If I remember anything else I'll place it here.

Comment: likely duplicate (see OP comment for answer below) of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46022/female-main-character-in-an-ice-world-earning-gems-runes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It could be the [Seventh Τower](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Seventh_Tower) series by [Garth Nix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garth_Nix).

[image]

It's fairly vague, though in the first book the protagonist has an encounter with a dragon shadow servant.

Comment: Yep, first thing that jumped to my mind. Shadows play a large role in this series and even start a war at some point IIRC.

Comment: This definitely sounds like it, I'll look into it when I get some free time and then I'll mark this as the answer if it matches. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The boy with two shadows, by Margaret Mahy.
http://www.penguin.co.nz/products/9780143504405/boy-two-shadows

A witch wants to go on holiday, so persuades a boy to look after her shadow, which sticks to his feet alongside his own.  But the boy's shadow is bullied by the witch's shadow, and runs away.

Comment: No I'm pretty sure this isn't it, thanks for trying though.